# Hull kernel topology and $\tau_w$-topology are same on Prime$(A)$

Tags: ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and Id$(A)$ denotes the space of ideals of $A$. A subbasis for $\tau_w$-topology is given by the collection $$U(J)= \{ I \in Id(A): I \nsupseteq J \}, J \in Id(A)$$

Let Prime$(A)$ denotes the space of prime ideals of $A$. Equip Prime$(A)$ with hull kernel topology.

> Is it true that restriction of $\tau_w$-topology on Prime$(A)$ is same as hull kernel topology?

Any ideas or references?

Comment: I have not studied that stuff, but I have definitely seen them in paragraph 5.3 of Murphy's "C*-algebras and Operator Theory"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it that you are studying?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, I am basically studying about ideals of tensor product of $C^*$-Algebras.

Comment: I am studying about C*-tensor products (nuclearity mostly)!

Comment: I'm not sure, I just remember this section having a study of Prim(A) endowed with some topology..